# What it mean by BAREMETAL motherboard

Tags: motherboard

What it mean by BAREMETAL motherboard?
Does it equal to PC motherboard?

Any example for baremetal motherboard

Edit:
I am seeking solution .. I was asked to find worst case execution time of a program in C program in baremetal motherboard

Confused what to do with baremental without OS

Comment: If you don't know what it is, how do we know what it is? Its a term that I've never seen before, and without context, its pretty hard to tell what the person who used the term was meaning (or smoking)

Comment: ... *You're* the one asking the question. *You* show *us* the example.

Comment: Baremetal Restore means the backup has a boot mechanism to bring a computer back from complete drive wipe. Baremetal motherboard means??? A motherboard with nothing installed on it? A motherboard with only the power supply attached? It's not a term I've come across in the 25 years I've been assembling computers from components. Now Air Chassis is easy, assemble the components without a case, power up for a dry run to see if it all works together.

Comment: Bare-metal hypervisor, Bare-metal OS, still no Bare-metal motherboard. Guess I'll have to get out the sander so I can see traces...

Comment: It may refer to a system running without an OS

Comment: Journeyman Geek - I get various ans here too..plz conclude if you know...


Ignacio Vazquez-Abram -How come i know even you dont know what it is?

Comment: If its a question asked in school, well, ask them what they mean?

Answer (score 2):

in this case 'baremetal' means that the code you are executing is being compiled directly into your chipset's machine langague, and is executed without additional software. C is a baremetal langague, whereas java, is not. When java code executes, it is run through multiple layers of interpreter software.

see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265357/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages

I believe you are worring about this too much. the reason your instructor mentioned C and Baremetal, is they don't want you to consider more complicated means of execution, and to just focus on the most basic case without any other details getting in the way. your Big-O and execution time calculations are purely theoretical anyway, so you ignore a lot of little details in the process. as long as you can compare them between algorithms, and pick the fastest suitable algorithm, thats all you really need anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "baremetal" motherboard.

"baremetal" implies a fresh install with only the hardware to start with.

Maybe someone is using the term wrongly to imply a motherboard without CPU, memory or anything plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

"Bare metal" refers to any equipment whatsoever that has nothing else added to it. A bare metal panel is unpainted and untreated. A bare metal circuit board has no components. A bare metal assembly has no changes made to it after it has been assembled. So a bare metal motherboard is in the original condition it was in when it came off the O.E.M.'s assembly line, no CPU, no memory, no firmware updates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're confusing `baremetal` and `barebones`.

When talking about virtualization and datacenters, `baremetal` refers to as the physical machine and hardware. For example, if I am doing software development and if I need to run a few different Operating Systems for testing of the software, it might be suggested that I run a `baremetal hypervisor` like ESXi, Proxmox or Xenserver and from there install Virtual Machines of  the different operating systems. However, this `baremetal hypervisor` does not have any sort of indication that it is a basic configuration as it may be a rather customized and beefy machine.

`Barebones` usually refers to a simple computer with casing, powersupply, cpu, ram, etc. This can vary based on the product being offered, but it is typically the absolute necessities required for a simple setup.

Answer (score 0):

"Baremetal motherboard" - I've never heard this term.

"Bare metal" is a term to mean "on physical hardware, outside of any OS."  For example, if you do a bare metal install of an OS, you are installing on a physical storage device on a physical system.

So your teacher was probably trying to emphasize that you should NOT use an emulator or any virtualization software to reach your result.